# JSR-308 extension of JSR-305?

Tags: java, annotations

Eclipse's null analysis now supports JSR-308, i.e. you can now put `@Nonull`, etc. on generic type parameters.

However, the widely-used `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0` package does not have the JSR-308 specific targets. Is there any JSR-308 oriented version of this or a way to extend the JSR-305 null annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, in Eclipse at least, the semantics of the annotations changed, so an annotation that targets both usage could be dangerous.

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis
- http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_type_annotations.htm&cp=1_3_9_1

Answer (score 1):

JSR 305 was abandoned long ago (a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jsr-305/4vqYTAuWncY) about its status was asked to its mailing list in 2010 but never answered).  You should not expect JSR 305 to evolve to take advantage of new features of Java such as type annotations (JSR 308).

On the other hand, there are many definitions of annotations that you can use in place of the JSR 305 versions.  For example, the Checker Framework manual lists [11 variants of the @NonNull annotation](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-related-work) that you can choose from.

You are probably best off choosing annotations that are defined so that they can be used in type annotation locations.  (Or, you could create a nonstandard version of the JSR 305 annotations that adds TYPE_USE to the @Target meta-annotations.)